# Mysql view variable

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql view for my project. It is great solution for my problem (check, if date expired). But I have a small problem and I can not find it on stack or in their documentation. Maybe I miss some basic from mysql or I do know. So here is problem:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `view_dl_status` AS
    select 
        `dl`.`Id` AS `Id`,

        (now() <= `dl`.`validTo`) AS `isValidFlag`
    from
        `devicesloc` `dl`
```

this solution works perfect. But when I want use isValidFlag (it is variable, not column),

```
(`dl`.`status` = 1 AND `view_dl_status`.`isValidFlag` = 0) AS `valid`
```

or

```
(`dl`.`status` = 1 AND `isValidFlag` = 0) AS `valid`
```

it is not working. 
Error:

> Unknown column 'isValidFlag' in 'field list'

I understand, that is not column, but is it possible get this value? It wil be great. Thanks

Comment: Is the error caused when you are trying to create another column in that view definition? You cannot use column aliases in other column definitions. try `(dl.status = 1 AND NOT(now() <= dl.validTo)) AS valid`

Comment: Hi that is solution too. Thanks. Can I add some difficult conditions? Not only true/false? Thanks alot for quick response

Comment: You can do whatever you would like but I would assume you would want to add expressions resulting in true/false to your `valid` column since `valid` is currently a Boolean answer.

Comment: yes, it is but I want something like that - (dl.status = 1 AND NOT(now() <= dl.validTo)) valid=1. (dl.status = 2 AND NOT(now() <= dl.validTo)) valid = 2 etc. Anyway can you please note answer, I really want you some points for right answer, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a column alias in the definition of another column. So you would need to repeat the entire column definition in the new column.

For instance, `(dl.status = 1 AND NOT(now() <= dl.validTo)) AS valid`.

That being said there are a few variations that may help you regarding maintainability and readability, especially since you are encapsulating your logic into a view.

Assuming your goal is this:

```
SELECT  `dl`.`Id` AS `Id`,
        (now() <= `dl`.`validTo`) AS `isValidFlag`,
        (dl.status = 1 AND NOT(now() <= dl.validTo)) AS valid
FROM `devicesloc` `dl`
```

You could re-write it as

```
SELECT Id, isValidFlag
   , (status = 1 AND isValidFlag = 0) AS valid
FROM (SELECT  `dl`.`Id` AS `Id`, `status`.`Id` AS `status`,
            (now() <= `dl`.`validTo`) AS `isValidFlag`
      FROM `devicesloc` `dl`)
```

And since you are using views, you could make a view of a view

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT  `dl`.`Id` AS `Id`, `status`.`Id` AS `status`,
        (now() <= `dl`.`validTo`) AS `isValidFlag`
FROM `devicesloc` `dl`
```

Then

```
CREATE VIEW view2 AS 
SELECT Id, isValidFlag
       , (status = 1 AND isValidFlag = 0) AS valid
FROM view1;
```